# Whistling at/to/for

Tags: word-choice

He headed for the door, whistling **at**/**to**/**for** his little brother, who was busy playing with Lego, to come with him.

Which one of these is correct or just more natural?

Answer (score 1):

None of them would be wrong as such. But the idiomatic expression when drawing someone's attention for the purpose of having them come with you is **whistle *for***.